# How to multiply a row of an array by the value stored in the corresponding row of a vector?

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following setup:

```
a = np.asarray([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
s = np.asarray([1, 2])
```

I would like to multiply `a[0] * s[0]` and `a[1] * s[1]` to get

```
[[1, 2, 3],
 [8, 10, 12]]
```

How can I do this easily? And if possible, I would like to avoid a reshape.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a reshape?

Comment: I'm executing this code on a GPU, and I was originally unsure of the performance impact of a reshape. After reflecting on it, I realized reshaping should be fine, since all arrays are essentially 1-dimensional (in memory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a * s[:, np.newaxis]
```

Broadcasting goes through the shapes in the opposite direction from what you want, so we stick another axis in there. (This is very similar to a reshape.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll end up using the reshape solution, but your answer addressed all of the constraints I posed in my question.